# Where are the indoor maps located in the REST API of Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

[This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#indoor_maps) URL gives information about the indoor maps and floor plans.

I can't seem to find them in the discovery do documents of the REST API, any tips or hints?

Comment: The Google Maps API is not discoverable through the Google API Discovery Service.  Google Maps is exposed through the docs.  What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @Rob, I would like to understand the schema so I can implement it in an IoT schema to determine locations

Comment: If you're referring to something like HATEOAS, the Google Maps API isn't a RESTful API.  Perhaps you could describe the problem in a little more detail.